# MS SQL Server - Login timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

I am doing this tutorial of Microsoft: Basic Data Mining Tutorial

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167167.aspx

I am using SQL Server 2012 and SSIS - SQL Server Integration Services
but I got stuck on one problem,... it says: "Login time expired" ... it cannot connect to SQL Server...

I turned off the Windows Firewall but it didn't help. 
I also made sure that TCP/IP and Named Pipes are ENABLED within SQL Server...

Any ideas?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try right clicking the sql server in management studio and checking the 'Connections' tab and verify "Allow remote connections to this server" is checked.

Comment: Is the SQL Server local or remote? Did you restart the instance after changing the TCP/IP setting?